# How to vectorize this for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, vectorization

I don't have much experience in R. I have a for loop like this:

```
combination<-read.csv(choose.files())
rownames(n_weight)<-1:154
colnames(n_weight)<-rownames(n_weight)
for(i in 1:length(n_weight)){
  for(j in 1:length(n_weight)){
  if(i==j){
    n_weight[i,j]<-1
  }
}}

idex <- dim(combination)[1]   #idex is length 
m <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = idex, nrow = idex))
rownames(m) <- as.numeric(combination$FID)
colnames(m) <- rownames(m)



# n_weight: 154X154 matrix
# m: 23562*23562 matrix
# combination: data.frame with 23562 obs. 

for(i in 1:23562){
  for (j in 1:23562){
    if(n_weight[combination[i,]$PC,combination[j,]$PC]==1){
      if(n_weight[combination[i,]$RC,combination[j,]$RC]==1){
        m[i,j]<-1}
    }}}
```

This is taking too much of time. Is there a way to vectorize this loop?
Thank you!

Comment: You should include the `n_weight`, `m` and `combination` objects in your question. And reduce your data set to a small example that demonstrates your issue. And describe the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: `combination<-read.csv(choose.files())` doesn't help; we don't have access to your files. Just create an example data set like `combination <- data.frame(x = ..., y = ...)`

Comment: the first for loop seems like the diagonal. Just do `diag(n_weight) = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
met_conditions <- ifelse(n_weight[combination$PC, combination$PC] == 1 & 
     n_weight[combination$RC, combination$RC] == 1, TRUE, FALSE)

m[met_conditions] <- 1
```